Laptop Power/Battery issues
I am using Linux Mint xfce 21.3 on an Acer A515-51-58XP laptop. Last couple of weeks I am facing strange issue with powering on the laptop on random occasions (approx. 3 out of 10 times). The laptop on light (blue light) glows but nothing happens (screen remains blank). I don't even get a chance to go to BIOS.
I checked my battery health using upower. The capacity shows 100% (although it is 5 years old!). Once the laptop starts it runs without any issues. I have used it for nearly 2 hours on battery.
I am not sure whether this is relevant to the issue. But last couple of months, (again randomly, not always) I keep getting notified alternately Battery charging/discharging notification every 30 seconds or so. Is there any way to find out whether this power on issue is a hardware/Battery/BIOS/OS issue? I can of-course replace the battery if I am sure that is the source of problem. Thanks!

I can you clarify somethings up? How can you run upower if you can't get into BIOS or the OS

And the notification of battery charging/discharing is completely normal, beacause for some batterys, once the charge get to 100%, it will starts to release power then recharge again, so on to maintain 100% charge, just disable the notification. And the capacity shows 100% might be or might not be a problem depending on your battery model, some battery just dosn't have function of checking health.

@james OP says he's still able to power the laptop on most of the time, it only fails 3 out of 10 times, that may answer your first question.

The battery charge/discharge, as it began recently, indicates there is some problem in there. I would guess it is most likely to be a hardware fault. Replacing the battery is probably the easiest thing to try, but you should also gently but firmly manipulate the cables on the laptop and see if that triggers this warning in any sort of correlating way (eg, you cause those notifications when you wiggle the power cord, for instance). If replacing the battery doesn't solve this, and wiggling cords doesn't correlate to the warnings, there will likely be an internal connection fault.

You seem to be conflating two issues: 1. Battery charge notifications. 2. Boot issues. If you believe the battery might be the cause of the boot problem, does that boot issue also occur when plugged into AC power? If so, then likely it has nothing to do with the battery.

@james - As music2myear pointed out, it doesn't always fail. The fact that I have used the laptop on battery for 2 hours would, I assume, mean that battery is ok

@music2myear Yes, I am sure there are no issues with cable or the power source. Nor am I able to see any specific pattern in the failures (i.e., relating to with or without AC power etc.). But once thing for sure- when it fails immediate retries don't seem to work. Only after a gap of 5/10 minutes it works. When it fails I have to do hard shut down (press and hold the power button)

@DrMoishe - I mentioned the notification issue just in case that is related to power on. I am not bothered much about the notification although it can be a bit distracting. Failures happen both whether connected to power  or not.

Just to me clear, your laptop can sometimes boot successfully into OS but some times can't with 50% chance?

Can you do some test with it? First remove the battery, then plug AC charger into it, see if it can boot successfully, if so then it's something to do with battery power line or battery it self. If still not successfully booting, examen the mother board for tiny burns on the IC(Those burns are normally really really tiny)

@james Yes, 70% of the time it boots successfully. 30%, when it fails I have to keep trying after hard shutdown. Will give a try to the tests that you have suggested.

Your laptop is experiencing a static charge whereas  it is already powered on. To release the static charge, removing the power cord and battery then  hold the power button for 30 seconds. After 30 seconds put the power cord back in (leave the battery out) then press the power button to see what happens. If nothing happens remember that the laptop can work off the power cord or the battery, but the battery receives a charge from the power cord.if the power cord is bad, the battery will eventually drain and you’ll have no power source to make the laptop power on.

Sorry need more clarity. When I press the power button the blue LED comes on but nothing seems to happen, i.e., the screen doesn't turn on nor do I hear any sound (of fan or the drive). The only thing that I can do when this happens is to do a hard shut down (press and hold power button). Other things that I have tried without any success are: close the laptop lid and reopen, pulling out/turning off AC power, wait for sometime. I also don't think it is a screen issue since 7 out of 10 occasions everything including the screen just works fine
